# Linq-to-Entities Include method not found

Tags: entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I am using EF4 within a MVC3 application and I was looking for a way to view all my contacts within a given workgroup. In the controller I specified:

```
var wg = from w in _repo.Workgroups.Include("Contact").ToList();
```

but I get the following error:

> 'System.Linq.IQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'Include' and no extension method 'Include' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I though this method was built into EF4. Do I have enable it somehow?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes the method is build into EF but it is not available on `IQueryable` interface. It is available on `ObjectQuery`. If you want to call it on `IQueryable` you must create your own extension wich will convert current query to `ObjectQuery` and perform `Include`. Something like:

```
public static IQueryable<T> Include<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, string property)
{
  var objectQuery = query as ObjectQuery<T>;
  if (objectQuery == null)
  {
    throw new NotSupportedException("Include can be called only on ObjectQuery");
  }

  return objectQuery.Include(property);
}
```

Or you must use [Entity Framework Feature CTP5](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=35adb688-f8a7-4d28-86b1-b6235385389d) where such extensions are already available.

Comment: Add the Data.Entity namespace:
e.g., using System.Data.Entity;

Answer (score 91):

I was also getting this error and resolved it by adding the following reference:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

Comment: Can't believe it was that easy after spending so much time trying to figure it out. Thanks @BruceHill

Comment: I also couldn't believe how easy the solution was, and that no one had given this answer to a question that was over a year old at the time. So, no problem, Adrian. Glad that I could help.

Comment: Still an valuable answer for people in 2020 :)

Answer (score 10):

Bruce Hill's answer is absolutely right.

Just to expand on his answer a bit, the Include methods are extension methods in the System.Data.Entity namespace.

It doesn't affect how you use them, but the Include methods are actually defined in a static class named DbExtensions. At msdn.microsoft.com, you'll see them documented there, not under System.Linq.IQueryable, making them just a bit harder to find.

Answer (score 4):

I was also facing this issue and resolved it in asp.net core 3.0 project by adding the following reference:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

Comment: I believe this is now the correct answer for projects using EF Core, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56285270/what-is-the-equivalent-of-system-data-entity-in-entity-framework-core-2-2-4

Answer (score 0):

If this issue is coming from a Stored Procedure, ensure that the SP is working fine.

Entity Framework will try predict the kind of return value from the Stored Procedure, and if SP is not working because of invalid Table name or column within it, it returns an Integer, and the Entity Framework creates a Conceptual Schema expecting an integer as return value instead of a table.