# ObjectContext instance has been disposed error

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I am new to EF and I have the following query:

```
List<Test.MemberAccount> userAccounts = new List<Test.MemberAccount>();
using (var context = new CoopEntities1())
{
    var query = from s in context.MemberAccount
                join sa in context.AccountType on s.account_type_id equals sa.id
                where s.member_guid == memberID
                select s;

    userAccounts = query.ToList();
}

return userAccounts;
```

Problem is when I load the page I get the following error:

"The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection."

Any help would be fantastic.

Error in detail:

```
AccountType = '((new System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_CollectionDebugView<Test.MemberAccount>
(userAccounts)).Items[0]).AccountType' 
threw an exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException'
```

Comment: Are you sure that this is the code that is causing your exception?  You are resolving your query to an in-memory collection with .ToList() so this code doesn't seem to suspect.

Comment: Yes, Look: AccountType = '((new System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_CollectionDebugView<Test.MemberAccount>(userAccounts)).Items[0]).AccountType' threw an exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException'

Comment: It looks like you're accessing a navigational property after you've returned your list. Lazy loading is trying to use the invalid context.

Comment: That may be it. How would I go about with fixing this issue? Or is it impossible and I need to look for an alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AccountType is not being eagerly loaded.  Since you're sticking to query syntax, it would look like the following:

```
List<Test.MemberAccount> userAccounts = new List<Test.MemberAccount>();
using (var context = new CoopEntities1())
{
    var query = (from s in context.MemberAccount
                join sa in context.AccountType on s.account_type_id equals sa.id
                where s.member_guid == memberID
                select s).Include("AccountType");

    userAccounts = query.ToList();
}

return userAccounts;
```

If intellisense is missing, make sure to include the following using statement:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

Comment: Hmm, weird, after I close the parenthesis I get no option to type Include.

Comment: Ah, nevermind had to use 'using System.Data.Entity;'

Comment: @LordRelix, If it were me (and I haven't used EF6, just 4), I would apply the Include earlier => context.MemberAccount.Include(...), and you can omit the join since you're not using it in your query and EF would know what to do based on the relationship.

Comment: Ah I see. Yes I added the Include earlier as you suggested and it works. Thanks a million, learned a few things =)

Answer (score 2):

You need to [eagerly load](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) AccountType for your MemberAccounts:

```
List<Test.MemberAccount> userAccounts = new List<Test.MemberAccount>();
using (var context = new CoopEntities1())
{
    userAccounts = context.MemberAccount
                    .Where(m => m.member_guid == memberID) 
                    .Include(m => m.AccountType) 
                    .ToList();
}

return userAccounts;
```

Comment: take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256692/linq-to-entities-include-method-not-found

Comment: Nevermind, had to use using System.Data.Entity;

Comment: Yep that would do the trick :)

Comment: I went with David's answer due to the fact I prefer query style, but thanks a lot your suggestion also worked in case anyone else needs reference like I did. Thanks!