# What is the equivalent of System.Data.Entity in Entity Framework Core 2.2.4?

Tags: c#, .net-core-2.2

I try to use the `IObjectSet` interface in a project in .NET Core 2.2, but with the version of Entity Framework Core 2.2.4, it does not work.

This is in .NET Core 2.2.0

```
IObjectSet<TEntity> GetGroup<TEntity>() where TEntity : class, IObjectWithChangeTracker;
```

> The name of the type or namespace 'IObjectSet<>' was not found.

Answer (score 3):

You need to update EF7 .In EntityFramework  `System.Data` is version 6, in that case, you can use  `System.Data` and in EF7 you should use EntityFramework.* nuget packages
Like below

```
 using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.*;
```

Read the documentation before use
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/tree/d1b10fc6ccca83e29109a0a8d9c047f2e68aede5

Comment: thanks, check and there's still no equivalent in Entity Framework Core 2, actually in EF7 if it works for me, but I'm doing the migration and I run into this dealle.